# Usage of RootWeb property instead of OpenWeb method

Tags: sharepoint

I am referring a SharePoint book and I found the following code snippet in an example in that book.

```
using (SPSite mySiteCollection = new SPSite(mySiteUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb mySPSite = mySiteCollection.RootWeb)
    {
       //your code here.
    }
}
```

I read through the usage of RootWeb property over OpenWeb() method all over the internet and found that we should never use RootWeb property inside of a 'using' statement. But in this book, they always use RootWeb for create SPWeb object. And everything works perfectly.

Can anybody tell me how should I use RootWeb property over OpenWeb method? And what are the pros and cons using each of them. Actually I found similar question in here. But it doesn't provide the answer for my question.

Answer (score 2):

Disposing the `SPWeb` instance from the `RootWeb` property is plain wrong - it will be automatically disposed with its parent which is `SPSite`. Disposing `RootWeb` may cause problems if you try to work with the property later. Refer to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557362%28v=office.14%29.aspx) on MSDN for best practices on disposing SP object.

IMHO you should prefer the `RootWeb` property instead of the `OpenWeb` method because you do not have to dispose the `SPWeb` instance explicitly. But it may be just a matter of preference.

Comment: Note the part about the guidance has changed - the used to recommend disposing .RootWeb but now don't so your book was probably written before the guidance was updated.